# format a NSDate to DDMMYYYY?

Tags: ios, nsdate, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

I have to send a DDMMYYY date from a Date to communicate with an API.

NSDateComponents *dateComponents;
NSCalendar *gregorian;
NSDate *date;

```
gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
self.date = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
```

Do I have to use the [dateComponents day] and so on? is there some method that can help me to performing that task like in PHP?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"ddMMyyyy"];
NSString *textDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];
NSLog(@"Date %@",textDate);
[dateFormatter release];
```

Comment: There is missing semi-colon ; at the end of the NSLog statement, but otherwise works perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Just:

```
  NSDateFormatter *outputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [outputFormatter setDateFormat:@"ddMMyyyy"];
  NSString *textDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[outputFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];
  [outputFormatter release];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"] autorelease]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"ddMMyyyy"];
NSDate *current = [NSDate date];
NSString *currentstring = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:current]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    NSDate *date=[NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"ddMMyyyy"];
    NSString *dateOfGame =[formatter stringFromDate:date];
    [formatter release];
```

Comment: finally that sounds not hard, but I had to know all the possibilities of the language... hum :-)

Comment: all the possibilities of the language ?? It is not understood to me

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"ddMMyyyy"];

NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree With **Ruben Esposito**

Just change your code like this.

```
NSDateFormatter *dtFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dtFormatter setDateFormat:@"ddMMyyyy"];    
NSString *strDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dtFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];
[dtFormatter release];
NSLog(@"%@",strDate);
```