# Time format in specific format

Tags: ios, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [format a NSDate to DDMMYYYY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894096/format-a-nsdate-to-ddmmyyyy)
>   [Want NSDateformatter for January,2000 or January 2000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134621/want-nsdateformatter-for-january-2000-or-january-2000)

I need date and time in following format. How can I get ..

Dec 17,2012 5:30 AM

Comment: Read the API spec for NSDate.

Comment: You're not doing very well with your questions you've asked. Perhaps you should try reading the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: Bookmark [this](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action), and observe the "search" box in the upper right corner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always google for these kind of issues

Try to look at [**NSDateFormatter**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003643) Class,
The format you are looking for is something like:

```
 [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd,yyy hh:mm:ss a"]; //dateFormatter is an object of class NSDateFormatter
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSDate *selected_Date = //Your Date object here;
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMM dd,yyy hh:mm:ss a"];
    NSString* strDateObj [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dateFormat stringFromDate:selected_Date]];
    NSLog(@"Date %@",)
```